Are 2x2g Hynix HMT125U6DFR8C-H9 (DDR3 1333MHz]) RAM compatibility with my system?
I have desktop PC with motherboard GA-H81M-HD3. I know that there are newer ones with RAM 8G Kingston 99U5403-160.A00LF (DDR3 1600MHz, here).
Are 2x2g Hynix HMT125U6DFR8C-H9 (DDR3 1333MHz, here) RAM compatibility with my system?

Go directly to the sites that show compatibility, , e.g., Kingstons's, https://www.kingston.com/en/memory or Crucial's, https://www.crucial.com/products/memory/memory-buying-guide . Hardware purchase is off-topic here.

When having two rams of different frequencies the system down-clocks to the slower RAM.
My suggestion is to check your CPU supported ram frequency, if that value is 1333 MHz or lower then there would be no difference, otherwise it might slow down your computer.

Thanks for reply - according to sysinfo , CPU is :  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz, 3201 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s) - so as I understand correct it can slow down ?

@user37137 - If you are currently using 600 MHz DDR3 and you install 1333MHz DDR3, then all modules will run at 1333 Mhz. You will unlikely be able to see any difference in performance outside of benchmarks.
